# Html checkbox event listener not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple checkboxes with same names and all off them can be accessed from javascript but **I can not add event listener for any of them.** 
I have tried all the solutions that i found in the internet. But in my case, none of them worked, means my target listener method **selectAll** is not being called. My codes are as follows

HTML

```
<div class="row" th:each="bytesaver : ${bytesaverList}">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="x_panel">
        <div class="x_title">
            <h2 th:text="${bytesaver.name}">Bytesaver 1</h2>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="x_content">
            <div>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <th>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control flat" name="checkBoxByteSaver" th:value="${bytesaver.name}"/> 
                            Select All
                        </th>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- x_content -->
    </div>
    <!-- x_panel -->
</div>
<!-- available IP List -->
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var selectAllBoxs = document.getElementsByName("checkBoxByteSaver");
console.log("total element count: "+selectAllBoxs.length)
for (var i = 0; i < selectAllBoxs.length; i++) {
    //selectAllBoxs[i].change(selectAll);
    console.log("Value: "+selectAllBoxs[i].value +" boolean: "+selectAllBoxs[i].addEventListener);

        selectAllBoxs[i].addEventListener ("CheckboxStateChange", selectAll, false);

}
}

function selectAll(){
    console.log("Select All pressed");
}
```

in the place of `selectAllBoxs[i].addEventListener` i have tried some other methods like 
`selectAllBoxs[i].onclick = function() {
                selectAll();
            }`

and

```
selectAllBoxs[i].addEventListener( 'change', function() {
        if(selectAllBoxs[i].checked) {
            console.log("Some checkbox is selected. Value: "+selectAllBoxs[i].value);
        } else {
            // Checkbox is not checked..
            console.log("Some checkbox is unselected. Value: "+selectAllBoxs[i].value);
        }
    });
```

and

```
if (selectAllBoxs[0].addEventListener) {
    for (var i = 0; i < selectAllBoxs.length; i++) {
       selectAllBoxs[i].addEventListener("change", selectAll, false);
     }
    } else if (selectAllBoxs[0].attachEvent) {
     for (var i = 0; i < selectAllBoxs.length; i++) {
       selectAllBoxs[i].attachEvent("onchange", selectAll);
     }
    }
```

but unfortunately none of them worked.

Comment: `value` of a checkbox does **not** change. Only the `checked`  property.

Comment: Actually I did not try to change the value. Just tried to add an event listener. But event listener not working here Sir.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "is not working"?

Comment: Listener not being called.

Comment: are you using jquery? , then why not use jquery change event

Comment: No. I am only using javascipt.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {});  This is jquery

Comment: $('input:checkbox').live('change', function(){
     if($(this).is(':checked')){
         alert('checked');
     } else {
         alert('un-checked');
     }
 });


I have tried something like this too.

Answer (score 1):

`value` of a checkbox does **not** change. Only the `checked`  property. Checkboxes work different from what you're expecting.

If a checkbox is not checked, **it simply is not contained in the form submit**.

For this reason Thymeleaf generates a hidden text input for each and every checkbox which has a `th:field` binding.

Here's proof that a simple change listener **will get called**:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let cbs = document.getElementsByName('checkBoxByteSaver');

  for (let i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
    cbs[i].addEventListener('change', hubbaloo);
  }
})

function hubbaloo(e) {
  console.log(this.value, this.checked ? 'checked' : 'not checked');
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control flat" name="checkBoxByteSaver" value="foo" />
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control flat" name="checkBoxByteSaver" value="bar" />
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control flat" name="checkBoxByteSaver" value="baz" />
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control flat" name="checkBoxByteSaver" value="yo" />
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control flat" name="checkBoxByteSaver" value="yolo" />
```

Comment: Well then either your Javascript throws some error, is not executed, or your HTML is not what you've shown. You see it **does work**.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var selectAllBoxs = document.getElementsByName("checkBoxByteSaver");
  console.log("total element count: "+selectAllBoxs.length)
  for (var i = 0; i < selectAllBoxs.length; i++) {
    //selectAllBoxs[i].change(selectAll);
    console.log("Value: "+selectAllBoxs[i].value +"boolean: "+selectAllBoxs[i].addEventListener);

    selectAllBoxs[i].addEventListener ("change", selectAll, false);
  }
})

function selectAll(e){
    console.log("Select All pressed");
    if(e.target.checked) {
      console.log(e.target.value + " is checked");
    }
    else {
      console.log(e.target.value + " is unchecked");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" th:each="bytesaver : ${bytesaverList}">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="x_panel">
        <div class="x_title">
            <h2 th:text="${bytesaver.name}">Bytesaver 1</h2>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="x_content">
            <div>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <th>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control flat" name="checkBoxByteSaver" th:value="${bytesaver.name}" value="Select All 1"/> 
                            Select All 1
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control flat" name="checkBoxByteSaver" th:value="${bytesaver.name}" value="Select All 2"/> 
                            Select All 2
                        </th>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- x_content -->
    </div>
    <!-- x_panel -->
</div>
<!-- available IP List -->
```

just use `change` event instead of `CheckboxStateChange` event.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:https://jsfiddle.net/q0mc4gLx/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var selectAllBoxs = document.getElementsByName("checkBoxByteSaver");
    console.log(selectAllBoxs)
    console.log("total element count: " + selectAllBoxs.length)
    for (var i = 0; i < selectAllBoxs.length; i++) {
        //selectAllBoxs[i].change(selectAll);
        console.log("Value: " + selectAllBoxs[i].value + " boolean: " + selectAllBoxs[i].addEventListener);

        selectAllBoxs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                selectAll();
            }
        });

    }
})

function selectAll() {
    console.log("Select All pressed");
}
```

Comment: a) don't use external code sites to show or suggest code on Stackoverflow (unless necessary because stackoverflow snippets don't have the functionality required). b) it is unclear if the code you posted right in your answer has any changes compared to OP's code. c) You haven't added **any** explanations. **Very bad answer.**

Comment: 1)I have binded selectAllBoxs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {}); using this event. 2) Jsfiddle code is written by  me only not an external link

Comment: @SodrulAminShaon please check the working code in jsfiddle provided by me

Answer (score -1):

This will help you

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        var selectAllBoxs = document.getElementsByName("checkBoxByteSaver");


        $("input[name='checkBoxByteSaver']").each(function () {

            $(this).bind('change', selectAll);

        });

    });

    function selectAll() {
        debugger;
        console.log("Select All pressed");
    }
```